# Why is a minus 4 pixel difference on body width in IE

Tags: html, css

This is me just being obsessive but I have to know if there is an explanation for this behavior. I have a monitor with a 1280 X 1024 viewport. I have a site that I want centered on the page. I also want the site width to be 1280 pixels wide.

Now, with FF and Opera, I can set the body to 100% and my wrapper to 1260px (Accounting for the scrollbar) and I do not get a horizontal scrollbar. If I use IE7 or 8, I get a horizontal scrollbar.

FF and Opera calculate the body width at 1260px (Assuming a 17px scrollbar) while IE calculates it at 1259px. I've measured the scrollbar in IE and it's also 17px.

Why is this?

This is it...

```
@import url("reset.css"); <- Erik Meyers reset
html, body{
  width:100%;
  background:#ccc;
  font-size:100%;
  /**overflow-x:hidden;**/ <-- Works fine with overflow-x:hidden
  font-family:Arial;
}

#wrap-page{
  margin:auto;
  width:1263px;
}

#wrap-content{
  margin:0 5px;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div style="wrap-page">
      <div style="wrap-page">
        <div style="float:left;height:2000px;width:1263px;">The test</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Surinder, yes, I'm using a reset.

Comment: Just set `overflow-x: hidden;`, curse IE, and call it a day.

Comment: Hey mrtsherman, I agree and have done that but this is one of those things that just really irks me. I just thought I'd check to see if there was some sort of explanation for it; maybe something I was overlooking.

Comment: @user1709311 which one is outer div #wrap-page or wrap-content ?

Comment: I'm sorry Surinder, I forgot to post the html. I'll throw that up top right now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are u using reset css.

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

**[Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**

Or You can use ie\9 hack ..

If your CSS looked like this...

```
#myElement {
    width: 300px;
    width: 500px\9;
}
```

The result would be `#myElement` 500 pixels wide in IE 7, 8, & 9, while in all other browsers, `#myElement` would be 300 pixels wide.

http://webdesignandsuch.com/ie9-specific-css-hack/

Comment: Surinder, I'm already using a reset. Thanks. It was a good answer

Comment: Sure. Up top now. THanks for looking

Comment: It's posted up top. I just did it

Comment: i have looked your code. Your code is perfect , you can use ie specific css  i updated my answer..

Comment: Thanks Surinder. I've never seen that hack before. I'm going to try it now.

Comment: try giving .wrap-page{width:100%;} not in pixels.

Comment: OK, I've added the `\9` to the `wrap-page` element but I'm still getting the scrollbar. Weird, huh?

Comment: Why you are using wrap-pae class 2 times. ?

Comment: Well, I've got to admit that I'm not much of a CSS guru and maybe you can correct me on that but what I wanted to do was to have the entire page centered if a user had a viewport larger than 1280px. I thought I needed the second element for that. No? By the way, your 100% did work.

Comment: You can even see this .. no scroll even in ie i have tested .
http://jsbin.com/ujutez/3/watch

Comment: Ah, I see what you are referring to now with regard to wrap-page. That was an error on my part. There are only 2 elements that encompass the site; wrap-page and wrap-content. Thank you for the jsBin, I see that it works.